# How do I modify the boot menu for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I'd like to add an entry to the Windows 7 boot menu, but it seems that it is not as simple as editing the boot.ini file.  How to I add a new entry? I'm trying to install [xPUD](http://xpud.org/) using the instructions [here](http://xpud.org/download.en.html#tab-3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) provides an "easier" way to manage the windows boot loader.

I don't think it provides that much extra functionality beyond `bcdedit`, but if you'd rather not play with the command line it's a second option.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Vista and later, you should use the `bcdedit.exe` command line tool to edit the boot menu configuration instead of editing the boot config file by hand. The exact commands will vary depending on exactly what you need to do, but there is extensive [documentation from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731662(WS.10).aspx) as well as a [helpful tutorial on a Windows 7 Forum](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2676-bcdedit-how-use.html).